# Angular Material: CheckBox in mat-menu; Problem with dark themes

Tags: angular, checkbox, menu, angular-material, menu-items

You can't put a `<mat-checkbox>` in a `<mat-menu>` normally. If so, dark themes don't apply to the *text-part* of your `<mat-checkbox>` *(see the image at the end)*.

About `<mat-label>`s there is a similar issue. But the solution is simple:

- *Using* `<label mat-menu-item>` *instead of* `<mat-label>`*.*

Similarly about `button`s.

---

But I couldn't find a similar solution for `<mat-checkbox>`es! These are all states that I tested:

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <mat-label>Bad label</mat-label>
  <label mat-menu-item>OK label</label>
  <mat-checkbox>Problem here</mat-checkbox>
  <!-- ERROR:
  <mat-checkbox  mat-menu-item>
    Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
  </mat-checkbox>
  -->
  <br><mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
  <label mat-menu-item style="display:inline">Not good workaround</label>
</mat-menu>
```

***[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4ftuc?embed=1&file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html)***

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There appears to be a way to assign `menuitemcheckbox` to the `role` input, on the `mat-menu-item` directive... unfortunately, I am not clear on how it should work...

```
<!-- https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/3f1588f562a4abd85d6add87a4f6ed969ba56898#diff-4cc67949abfd84b09e8b7178ac357febR2134 -->
  <button mat-menu-item role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true">Checked</button>
  <button mat-menu-item role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false">Not </button>
```

With that being said, assigning the `mat-menu-item` class rather than the directive may be a viable workaround.

```
<mat-checkbox class="mat-menu-item">Problem here</mat-checkbox>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4ftuc-5s5k3t?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.html

Comment: As per https://github.com/angular/components/pull/14165, the role only controls the aria-role on the menu item. Adding first class mat-item-checkbox elements is coming in a future minor, maybe

Answer (score 9):

Since Angular Material 11 the `class="mat-menu-item"` Workaround introduced by Marshal seems to be broken. You can fix it by applying the `mat-menu-item` directive on a `div` wrapping your `mat-checkbox`.

```
<div mat-menu-item>
  <mat-checkbox>Problem here</mat-checkbox> 
</div>
```

Be aware that the checkbox is now only triggered when you click exactly on the checkbox, not when you press any other spot of the menu-item. This causes only a click animation. To workaround this you can register a `(click)="..."` listener on the wrapping div.

Comment: You're right, to add the click behaviour you can register the (click) like this: 

(click)="$event.preventDefault(); filterCheck._inputElement.nativeElement.click()"

Comment: should be `<div mat-menu-item>
  <mat-checkbox>Problem here</mat-checkbox> 
</div>`

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on Aki's answer:

```html
<div mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); cb.toggle()" (keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation(); cb.toggle()">
  <mat-checkbox class="mat-menu__checkbox" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" #cb>Problem No Longer Here</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

The wrapper div needs `(keydown.enter)` so the keyboard controls for the mat menu will still work correctly.  We also register a click event so if the user clicks on the right or left edges of the menu item it will toggle the checkbox.  `$event.stopPropagation()` is here to prevent the menu from closing while the user is interacting with the checkboxes.

Then add the following to your style sheet:

```css
.mat-menu__checkbox {
  height: 100%;
  &::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-layout {
    height: 100%;
    &::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-label {
      margin: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}
```

This style will make the label of your mat checkbox the full height of the menu item and keep it vertically centered.  This makes it so the checkbox can be clicked anywhere and it will trigger.